# Maven release plugin

Tags: maven

Hi Meier I have used the following goal 
    mvn org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.7:update-property - 
    Dproperty=emom.web.dependency.shr.version  -DallowSnapshots=true

My Job B pom.xml is

```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.safeway.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>emom-shr</artifactId>
     <version>${emom.web.dependency.shr.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Under the properties it has version harcoded

```
      <emom.web.dependency.shr.version>19.6.5- 
       SNAPSHOT</emom.web.dependency.shr.version>
```

My Job A pom.xml

```
         <groupId>com.safeway.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>emom-shr</artifactId>
        <version>20.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

When I run the above goal maven is picking the latest version i,e(20.1.0) 
from artifactory but when I check the pom.xml of Job B under properties it still says 19.6.5 I need a way to change the 19.6.5 or current version to latest version available. Am I doing something wrong not able to figure it out.

Comment: You need to reformat your question so that people can read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `versions:update-property` to update the content of properties in your POM.

See https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-property-mojo.html

Comment: Hey Meier, I have tried using                                                                                         mvn org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.7:update-property